# Automatic popup with Auth0-react instead of login button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0

Is there a way to have to the authentication appear when I load the application, instead of having a login button to prompt it?

I have tried to use useEffect and call loginWithRedirect since that's what appears, but I've had no luck. I am new to Auth0 and the following code is used from the setup guide:

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

function App() {
  const { isLoading, isAuthenticated, error, user, loginWithRedirect, logout } =
    useAuth0();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return <div>Oops... {error.message}</div>;
  }

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {user.name}{" "}
        <button onClick={() => logout({ returnTo: window.location.origin })}>
          Log out
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <button onClick={loginWithRedirect}>Log in</button>;
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` in the `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    //call your function
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolved this using the below pattern:

```
 const { loading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading || isAuthenticated) {
      return;
    }
    const fn = async () => {
      await loginWithRedirect({
        appState: { targetUrl: path }
      });
    };
    fn();
  }, [loading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, path]);
```

Source:
https://thinkster.io/tutorials/auth0-react-login-and-user-profile/protect-the-profile-route